# Kanban tool selection

Tags: project-management, visual-studio

We would like to use an electronic Kanban board. We have Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) and want to make the progress of the work visible. What are our options? Right now we are using a physical post-it system.

Comment: Questions here must be specific. Please state your minimum required features, the features that must be avoided, and the nice-to-haves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many tools that offer virtual boards, here are a few of my favourites:

- Trello - A very popular tool that is mostly free, unless you choose to pay for a few additional benefits.
- Temwork Projects - Allow you to add tasks and display them on a board
- Redbooth - Again another good tool with a board view
- Pivotal tracker - Always seen this to be simular to Trello, but a few more features.
- Active Collab - Offers a board view

I would probably suggest signing up for a free trial on all of these and seeing which ones fits your needs / has the functionality you need.

Answer (score 5):

[Trello](https://trello.com/) is a free, closed source collaboration tool that organizes your projects into boards. In one glance, Trello tells you what's being worked on, who's working on what, and where something is in a process. Trello works on desktop, mobile and Trello web application. The Trello web application supports Chrome, Internet Explorer 11/Edge, Firefox and Safari.

#### Features

- quick overview on front and back of cards
- easy organization with tags, labels and categories
- drag and drop functionality
- inline editing
- checklists, with progress meter
- easy uploading of files and attachments
- data filtering
- archiving of card records (e.g. comments and changes)
- deadline reminders
- email notifications
- activity log
- assign tasks
- voting feature
- information retrieval and backup
- SSL encryption of data
- texts and visuals fit any screen size
- search function
- mobile functionality to access boards on the go
- developer API

[**Trello** YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCRcOkXoOrU6sN1yCz20VmQw)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Visual Studio already, I would like to recommend [Eylean Board](http://www.eylean.com/tfs). It offers a two way integration with VSTS, meaning you can use both tools simultaneously.

You will be able to:

- Take full advantage of an electronic kanban board - custom process steps, WIP limits, reports
- Track your VSTS items trough the same work item number in both tools
- Add extensive task information to the task card - description, comments, documents, sub-tasks, assignments, etc.
- Use additional project management features like time tracking, reporting and more.

Answer (score 2):

**Jira** is often considered as de facto standard of project management tools.
It has huge amount of features, including Kanban board, Scrum board, it's own query language to skim through the tasks and many others...

But it is not free of charge, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you use a physical post-it system for now, the mpst comfortable tool for you will be http://kanbantool.com . It is very friendly and inituitive, as well as easily

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking for a Kanban tool to replace their sticky notes, here is my list of [20 best Kanban boards](https://teamhood.com/kanban/best-kanban-board-tools/) of 2021.

I know picking the right tool might be tricky, so this post includes a comparison table. Allowing you to narrow down the choices based on the requirements and only try out the tools that fit your needs.